Is there any point in keeping the delivery certificate ("attestation de remise") that is given when retrieving a new French passport?
One gets a delivery certificate ("attestation de remise") (specimen) upon retrieving a new French passport. Is there any point in keeping the delivery certificate?

According to the guidelines given here, the delivery certificate should be kept safe separately from the passport as it could be used in the case of loss, theft or renewal.

Whatever they might say, it's definitely useless for renewal if you still have your current passport (nobody asks you for it and it doesn't spare you any other requirement).
